# Problem in understanding the definitions

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

Here are my definitions for measurable set and Lebesgue measure of a set.
Now I am asked to show that closed subsets of Rd are*lebesgue measurable* 
. My question is
**Are the words "measurable " & "Lebesgue measurable" are same in meaning here?**
We use exterior measure to define measurable set.  Definitely exterior measure of a set and lebesgue measure of a set has difference, so Can I say

> lebesgue measure of a set relates measurable subset of Rd with exterior measure of set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in your context "measurable " & "Lebesgue measurable" are the same in meaning.

Note that in other contexts, "measurable" may denote something else, for instance Borel measurable.

So, when a set is Lebesgue measurable, its measure is equal to its outer (exterior) measure.